# How to keep method arguments names from obfuscation by ProGuard

Tags: kotlin, proguard

For given class:

```
class KeepMe(val keepThisArgument: Int) {
    fun keepMethod(keepThisArgument: Int) {
        println(keepThisArgument)
    }
}
```

and proguard configuration:

```
-keep class com.KeepMe { *; }
```

following code is produced by proguard:

```
public final class KeepMe {
  private final int keepThisArgument;
  
  public final void keepMethod(int paramInt) {
    System.out.println(paramInt);
  }
  
  public final int getKeepThisArgument() {
    return this.keepThisArgument;
  }
  
  public KeepMe(int paramInt) {
    this.keepThisArgument = paramInt;
  }
}
```

constructor and method argument names is changed from "keepThisArgument" to "paramInt". Is there a way to keep it from happening? I use net.sf.proguard gradle plugin, version 6.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is separate configuration to keep all argument names in all classes that are kept from obfuscating:

```
-keepparameternames
```